# Can I replicate simple object structure and use obj[prop] selection notation with classes in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

Coming from a JavaScript background this seems really confusing and needlessly complicated. But maybe I've misunderstood / missed something. I just want to create objects, assign and select dynamically named properties to / from them, and print out their structure so I can make sure the structure is correct. But it seems like with Python I need extra structural complexity in the Objects to do that.

In JavaScript, I can create a class just like in Python, or define it directly, and the object has the same simple structure in both cases:

```
class myObjClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = "val1"
        this.prop2 = "val2"
    }
}

// directly defined
const myObj1 = {
    prop1: "val1"
    prop2: "val2"
}

// defined from class
myObj2 = new myObjClass()

// logged
console.log(myObj1) // { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2" }
console.log(myObj2) // { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2" }

// dynamically assigned to
const imagineThisNameIsDynamic = "prop3"
myObj1[imagineThisNameIsDynamic] = "val3"
myObj2[imagineThisNameIsDynamic] = "val3"

// dynamically selected from
myObj1[imagineThisNameIsDynamic] // "val3"
myObj2[imagineThisNameIsDynamic] // "val3"
```

But in Python, it looks like to do this, you can't directly define an Object, only a Dictionary:

```
const myObj1 = {
    prop1: "val1"
    prop2: "val2"
}
```

Which is fundamentally different from an Object, so it wont be equivalent to the version of the Object created from a class. Yes you can add magic methods to the class to make it behave similar, but not the same.

Here's where my question is leading, specifically: Is it possible to define a class that is capable of using the `myObj1[prop3]` getter and setter notation without having to store the data in a sub-property? Based on what I'm reading in the docs and tutorials, to enable an Object to use that notation, you have to create a sub-property to set / get and the data to / from, like so:

```
class myObjClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "val1"
        self.prop2 = "val2"
        self.dict= {}

    def __getitem__(self, prop):
        return self.dict[prop]

    def __setitem__(self, prop, val):
        self.dict[prop] = val
```

If I have to do things this way, now when I log the structure of Objects in my project, I can't have that simple structure like:

```
imagineThisNameIsDynamic = "prop3"
myObj1 = myObjClass()
myObj1[imagineThisNameIsDynamic] = "val3"
myPrettyPrintFunc(myObj1) # { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3" }
```

Instead it's like:

```
myPrettyPrintFunc(myObj1) # { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", dict: { prop3: "val3" } }
```

Unless I want to use a native function `setattr` / `getattr` each time I need to access / define an object property, which I think makes for less readable / uglier code, so I'd really prefer the `obj[prop]` selection notation.

This might not seem like a big deal, but big picture, throughout a large scale project when you want your data structure as simplified as possible, that simpler object structure is nice to have. So did I misunderstand? Someone please clarify

Comment: Python and Javascript have fundamentally two different OOP models, class-based and prototype-based, respectively. There *is no* equivalent concept in Python to an `Object` in javascript. In Python, *everything* is an object, and all objects have a well-defined `type`, and that type is a class. Note, classes are really just syntactic sugar in JS.

Comment: Anyway, to dynamically access an attribute in python, you use `getattribute(some_object, "some_dynamic_name")`

Comment: "This might not seem like a big deal, but big picture, throughout a large scale project when you want your data structure as simplified as possible, that simpler object structure is nice to have." I don't agree. The *larger* your project becomes, the less you want to rely on ad-hoc objects. If you are very often dynamically setting attributes on your object, then probably your design is wrong, or you actually just want a `dict` object specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `getattr`?

```
class Thing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = "val1"
        self.prop2 = "val2"

    def __getitem__(self, prop):
        return getattr(self, prop)

t = Thing()

print(t["prop1"])
```

But, what's wrong with just `t.prop1`? Why is the square-bracket syntax so critical? It seems subjective.

Comment: Well I have no problem using `getattr` / `setattr` within a magic func definition in my class if that lets my outward synatix be square bracket. But yeah I mean square bracket notation does (subjectively) seem a lot neater / easier to read, especially when you're working with large scale data analysis projects, I'm accessing and writing dynamic object property names all over the place. But I think maybe you solved my problem? When I tried something like that I was getting an infinite recursion error, I'll check..

Comment: @J.Todd "I'm accessing and writing dynamic object property names all over the place."  yeah, that seems like the problem, but if it is the syntax you want, you can just do the above, and probably you want to define `__setitem__` as well

Comment: Yes this actually fixes the problem I was having. In the `__getitem__` definition, I was setting the property name via `self[prop] = val` which caused infinite recursion. Using `setattr` solves this. Facepalm. All this question writeup for such a simple mistake..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well they're not all necessarily *dynamic* in the sense that the property names are dynamically generated, but when you iterate through Objects in JS, you get the keys (`Object.keys()`) as strings and need to use the square bracket notation either way. Seems like iterating over object properties in Python you'd be doing a similar thing most of the time..

Comment: @J.Todd right, again, that just seems to me like fundamentally there is a design problem if you find yourself doing that. For what it's worth, you can do something like `for name, attribute in vars(some_object).items()` to iterate through the instance attributes of an object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you do much data analysis based work? And yeah, that `name` item is a string, and often times in data analysis you'll end up defining that same `name` string to another Object, so.. The bracket notation is handy. You really wanna call a function every time? Little extra typing and systax to look at

Comment: Yes, I do a lot of data analysis work. I don't find myself iterating over the names and values of attributes in an object frequently. But my main language is Python. When I write JS code, I'm basically writing Python. In JS. I suspect, you are doing the reverse.